# Insertar fecha en formato AM PM para un campo datetime SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

usando el plugin boostrap datetimepicker el formato de mi fecha es:

```
20-11-2019 11:04 AM
```

pero a cuando se inserta en la base de datos sql se inserta de la siguiente forma:

```
2019-11-20 00:00:00.000
```

pense que el problema era que mando un string e intento convertirlo a un datetime:

```
DateTime newfechaPlazo = DateTime.ParseExact(fechaPlazo, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo. Como solucionarlo?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como haces el insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al aplicar el `DateTime.ParseExact()` obtienes un DateTime con la fecha y hora, si pasa el mouse por sobre la variable deberias poder validar que aplico correctamente formato

Ahora bien la otra parte implica asignar el valor al momento de insertar o actualizar el registro, para eso deberias usar parametros

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>"))  
{  
    conn.Open();  

    string query = "INSERT INTO NombreTabla2 (campo1, plazo) VALUES (@param1, @plazo)";  
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))  
    {  

       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", textbox1.Text);  
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plazo", newfechaPlazo);  

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    }  
}
```

Si el campo en la tabla es del tipo `DateTime` cuando asignes el parametro del mismo tipo insertara la fecha y hora

Answer (score 0):

Es una duda frecuente. Las bases de datos almacenan la fecha y la hora en un formato estandarizado, contienen su valor exacto. No es posible que la almacenen de otra manera.
Debe ser el programador quien decida cual es el formato de salida que desea. La fecha es la que es, pero puede mostrarse de diferentes formas. Cada lenguaje de programación tiene sus reglas y métodos de formateo.
Si lo que quieres es ver esa fecha en SQL Server Management Studio en un formato concreto, debes [acudir a la función](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `CONVERT` o `FORMAT`.
En tu caso deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
select FORMAT(getdate(), 'dd-MM-yy hh:mm tt')
```

Comment: De preferencia, hay que evitar usar FORMAT porque puede hacer mucho más lenta una consulta. Me parece que hasta 40 veces más lenta.